# angular 4 web service 405 status response

Tags: web-services, angular, http, service, authorization

i'm trying to use a webservice from angular 4 project , but i have this issue  in the console of chrome browser :

[image]
for more details get method work correctly .

the adresse : 192.168.1.110:8000 is adress of my backend projet

the adresse : 192.168.1.110:4200 is adress of my frontend projet (angular)

what's wrong please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way browser works your request is blocked. You need to google how to enable CORS on *your development platform here*. Or you can search SO for what is and how to enable CORS.

Comment: there is a lot of thing about that , i'm looking to resolve that because it's about a small  tab to resolve it

Comment: What server do you run?

Comment: my backend is symfony but it plays a getway backend . in fact i using symfony for validation data server side . 
api<---->symfony<------>angular

Comment: I have never touched Symfony before but this https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle or this https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/87161/Allow-CORS-in-symfony2 should do.